# why i got this error in jsp pages while i am doing client side validation

Tags: java, jsp

type Exception report

message /basic/proceed.jsp (line: 28, column: 80) The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

for code line is

```
<s:form name="my_form" action="process_recharge"onsubmit="return validateform()" >
```

Comment: Review : Question is incomplete. Please post the complete error and it's stack trace. Do not forget to format it. Also add clear description of use case and sample code. Since It might be deployment issue also , Please describe the deployment details.

Comment: Which part of *"JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace"* is unclear, considering you *don't* have a space before the `onsubmit` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace

is pretty clear. in

```
<s:form name="my_form" action="process_recharge"onsubmit="return validateform()" >  
                                                ^
```

You are missing a space between the quote and the `onsubmit=`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Tomcat 7 add the parameter below to `catalina.properties`.

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false
```

bounce and re-test